# Filtering data by Navigation Property in EF Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have this small model:

```
class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Community { get; set; }
}

class Community
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Country { get; set; }
}

class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The **DbContext** is this:

```
public class SmallDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to create query that will retrieve the `Users` of a given `Country`

My bet using is this:

```
int countryId = 2:
var usersOfAGivenCountry = dbContext.Users
                                    .Where(community => community.Country.Id == countryId);
```

But I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Is this correct way to do it?

Also, I wonder how this will handle a null `Community` in a `User`.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to do that. NULL navigation properties won't effect this, as the access to the navigation property translates to a LEFT OUTER JOIN and therefore all properties of the navigation property are NULL in the temporary table (rather than the object as a whole)

Comment: @SuperJMN Is your problem solved ? Feel free to accept my answer to close topic thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct way. As some users say, the LINQ expression is translated to SQL correctly, with the correct WHERE and JOIN clauses. Also, it's not necessary to check for `null` when `FirstOrDefault` is used inside the LINQ to SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost that, i advice you to add condition in `null` case, and you have to declare the foreign keys in your models like :

```
class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CommunityId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CommunityId")] // facultative because it respects naming convention Modelname + "Id"
    public Community { get; set; }
}

class Community
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get;set; }
    [ForeignKey("CountryId")] // facultative because it respects naming convention Modelname + "Id"
    public Country { get; set; }
}
var usersOfAGivenCountry = dbContext.Users
      .Include(p => p.Community)
      .Where(community => community != null
             && community.CountryId == countryId);
```

And the line `.Include(p => p.Community)` is facultative if you enabled Lazy Loading mode, but i advice you to disable it

Comment: eagerly loading navigation properties just because the selection of the query is on the referenced tables is not necessary and will possibly clutter your context.

Comment: This sounds out of context because EF Core does not support lazy loading (yet). Also neither `null` check nor `Include` is needed when the query is translated to SQL and executed in database.